# Fixed name in rest service's input parameters

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I implemented a rest web service by **Jax-RS** and **CXF**.

```
@Path("/StudentServices")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public class Student
{
    @POST
    @Path("/save")
    public String persist(@QueryParam("StudentName") String name,
                          @QueryParam("StudentAge") String age)
    {
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        System.out.println("  Incomming student with = " + name + "    " + age);
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

Actually, I want to call the service with the url: `localhost:9000/StudentServices/save` 
and with the body message as **JSON**: {"StudentName": "John", "StudentAge": "30"}

but when the request arrived to persist method, its inputs is null or empty. I examined with some others way like **Jackson** annotations, **JAXB** annotations but no one worked correctly.

Furthermore, I want to fix parameters' name when my service has input primitive types and **String**, because when I use a class for input, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use @QueryParam to read the body of the request.

As specified in the @QueryParam docs, It binds the value(s) of a HTTP query parameter to a resource method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property. Values are URL decoded unless this is disabled using the Encoded annotation. so if you forward the request like below your exisiting code should work:

```
localhost:9000/StudentServices/save?StudentName=John& StudentAge=30
```

Now if you want to accept json request Then you will have to create seprate javaBean.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class StudentRequest {
  private String studentName;
  private int studentAge;

  // getter and setter
}
```

And in your Controller. (i.e. Student.)

```
@Path("/StudentServices")
public class Student {
@POST
@Path("/save")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public String persist(StudentRequest studentRequest)
{
    //your custom logic
 }
}
```

Also specify your produces or consumes annotation on method level. It gives flexibility to return some other content type from other method.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean there is no way else define a POJO?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the Parameter as `QueryParam` this means, that JAX-RS is expecting them as parameter added to your url, e.g. `localhost:9000/StudentServices/save?StudentName=John&StudentAge=30`

What you want is that the data is send in the body. So you can define a simple POJO:

```
public class Student {
    private String StudentName;
    private int StudentAge;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And use it as parameter in the JAX-RS method:

```
@POST
@Path("/save")
public String persist(Student student) {
    System.out.println("*******************************");
    System.out.println("  Incomming student with = " + student.getStudentName() + "    " + student.getStudentAge());
    System.out.println("*******************************");
    return "Hello " + student.getStudentName();
}
```

The JAXB provider is transforming your body data (JSON) into the corresponding POJO and you can access the data via the getters.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean there is no way else define a POJO?

Comment: You can use a `javax.json.JsonObject` as generic class: `public String persist(JsonObject data)` and access the data by using one of its methods like `.getString("StudentName")` to get the JSON data for StudentName as a String.

Comment: I could not use public `String persist(JsonObject data)` because when I sent a request, the server throws an exception: `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type`. My method signature is : `    @POST
    @Path("/call2")
    public void call(javax.json.JsonObject json)`

Comment: Add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` to the method.

Comment: Have you set the `Content-Type` header in your client side code to 'application/json'? Otherwise it might be automagically interpreted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I tried `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` above the method, but the same error still happened. Also, When the method's parameter type is String, the method invoked. I tested with `Postman` and didn't set any headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149487/discussion-between-georg-henkel-and-mjm).